# Dynamically update / 'refresh' javascript function

Tags: javascript, dynamic, refresh

I'm quite new to JavaScript and have come up on a problem which probably shows my naivety :( Here's a simplified version:

I have an array and a function which automatically creates a new `<p>` for each array element to display its contents on the page. I also have a button which calls a function to add a new element to the array. I had expected the initial function to recognize when the array changes and to dynamically create a new

for the new element. Of course, however, it does not. How do I make this happen?

I know that I could just set the function which executes when the button clicks to add a new

containing the new element itself, but this seems inelegant and may also cause me problems down the line. It seems like what I'm looking for is some kind of 'refresh' of the initial function. Any suggestions are really appreciated :) Thanks very much in advance!

Here's the code (JS fiddle linked below too):

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
function populate() {
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let para = document.createElement('p');
        para.innerText = array[i];
        let container = document.getElementById('container');
        container.appendChild(para);    
    }
}
populate();


document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function addToAray() { 
    array.push('e')
    console.log(array);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/willgph/sj6duz92/4/

Comment: If you would clear the container before adding the children, you could just call `populate()` again ...

Comment: The problem you are describing has been solved by popular web frameworks like Angular, Vue and React. You might want to consider looking into these.